# Error while build on Simple List form in AX7

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax7

I faced one issue while building Simple List form in AX7. I added all missing controls on form still its giving below error on build.

Pattern 'Simple List' requires a sub-pattern specified on control 'AXForm/Form name//Design/Controls/CustomFilterGroup'.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an error informing you, that you have **missing sub-pattern** you should search for *"unspecified"* in the Form Designer. This search will show you all nodes where you have a missing sub-pattern.

For me this seems the easiest way to find all places where there is still work to be done in the Form. By work to be done, I mean to apply a fitting sub-pattern.

Here is an example:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing the new changes in AX7, I found that we also need to apply sub-patterns on Custom Filters in Simple List form pattern otherwise form will not build successfully. So to apply sub patterns on custom filter group , right click on group, select apply pattern and then click on Custom and Quick Filters. This will apply sub patterns to custom filters and you will be able to successful build the form.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "form statistics". its show, how many object covered by patterns and there is left any unspecified object.

to do this: open form, right-click the form in the designer, and then select Addins > Form statistics.

its looks like: http://msdynamics.blob.core.windows.net/media/2015/09/formStatistics.png

source: https://ax.help.dynamics.com/en/wiki/form-styles-and-patterns/